# Улучшения блока справки по использованию меток

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, метки

Когда пишу вопрос, если поставить курсор в поле с метками, справа появляется блок инструкций. В нем:

1. Непереведенная строка.

   > [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Опечатка

   > [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPD: выбрал новые, более лаконичные варианты.

1. > tag characters: letters digits + # - .
   >
   > <s>► допустимые символы: буквы латиницы и кириллицы, символы + - . #</s>
   >
   > допустимые символы: a-z, а-я, 0-9, + - . #

Порядок символов специально поменял, чтобы нельзя было подумать, что точка — это просто точка в конце предложения.

2. > <s>► отделяйте метки друг от друга с помощью пробела, запятой или точк**и** с запятой</s>
   >
   > разделяйте метки с помощью пробела, запятой или точки с запятой